# Realm Sync client history using all of MongoDB Atlas Cluster Storage

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm, mongodb-realm

I'm trying out [MongoDB Realm Sync](https://www.mongodb.com/realm/mobile/sync)

My iOS application currently is using local Realm DB with around 4 MB of data.
Trying it out with MongoDB Realm Sync, everything works fine except that with 4 MB of my data, it is having a `__realm_sync.client_history` collection which takes up around 480 MB of storage on my 500 MB free cluster.

Seems like it is creating a document with a binary file of around 4 MB with every data change which seems weird.

Comment: What is in this collection?

Comment: @D.SM I've linked a Realm Sync application with my cluster in MongoDB, it has created the __realm_sync database to facilitate the sync, client_history collection keeps tracks of the changes I guess. Issue is it takes up all of the memory.

Comment: Might be helpful if you looked at some documents in it.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Where are you seeing these files and capacities? In the Realm Console? If so, what section? I am looking at our Collections and don't see anything like that. Maybe include a screen shot would add some clarity?

Comment: @Jay I'm seeing the files and capacities in MongoDB Compass.

Comment: You should be logged into an using MongoDB Realm, then the Realm Tab which then shows the applications and data usage. As mentioned above, can you include a screen shot of what you're seeing?